# Does SQL Server allow including a computed column in a non-clustered index? If not, why not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

When a column is included in non-clustered index, SQL Server copies the values for that column from the table into the index structure (B+ tree). Included columns don't require table look up.

If the included column is essentially a copy of original data, why does not SQL Server also allow including computed columns in the non-clustered index - applying the computations when it is copying/updating the data from table to index structure? Or am I just not getting the syntax right here?

Assume:

- `DateOpened` is `datetime`
- `PlanID` is `varchar(6)`

This works:

```
create nonclustered index ixn_DateOpened_CustomerAccount
on dbo.CustomerAccount(DateOpened)
include(PlanID)
```

This does not work with `left(PlanID, 3)`:

```
create nonclustered index ixn_DateOpened_CustomerAccount
on dbo.CustomerAccount(DateOpened)
include(left(PlanID, 3))
```

or

```
create nonclustered index ixn_DateOpened_CustomerAccount
on dbo.CustomerAccount(DateOpened)
include(left(PlanID, 3) as PlanType)
```

My use case is somewhat like below query.

```
select 
    case 
        when left(PlanID, 3) = '100' then 'Basic'
        else 'Professional'
    end as 'PlanType'
from 
    CustomerAccount
where
    DateOpened between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

The query cares only for the left 3 of `PlanID` and I was wondering instead of computing it every time the query runs, I would include `left(PlanID, 3)` in the non-clustered index so the computations are done when the index is built/updated (fewer times) instead at the query time (frequently)

EDIT: We use SQL Server 2014.

Comment: As a side note, When I was researching on this, I found SQL 2016 allows [Indexes on Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx).

Comment: The 2016 news is good to know - thanks!. The LEFT calculation can be ignored if you use a LIKE comparison, e.g. WHEN PlanID LIKE '100%'. No calculations are actually made, and the comparison functions about as fast as if the target string was a varchar(3) with an equals comparison as far as performance goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laughing Vergil stated - you CAN index persisted columns provided that they are persisted. You have a few options, here's a couple:

**Option 1: Create the column as PERSISTED then index it**

(or, in your case, include it in the index)

First the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerAccount
(
  PlanID int PRIMARY KEY, 
  DateOpened datetime NOT NULL,
  First3 AS LEFT(PlanID,3) PERSISTED
);
INSERT dbo.CustomerAccount (PlanID, DateOpened)
VALUES (100123, '20160114'), (100999, '20151210'), (255657, '20150617');
```

and here's the index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_CustomerAccount ON dbo.CustomerAccount(DateOpened) 
INCLUDE (First3);
```

Now let's test:

```
-- Note: IIF is available for SQL Server 2012+ and is cleaner
SELECT PlanID, PlanType = IIF(First3 = 100, 'Basic', 'Professional')
FROM dbo.CustomerAccount;
```

Execution Plan:
[image]
As you can see- the optimizer picked the nonclustered index.

**Option #2: Perform the CASE logic inside your table DDL**
First the updated table structure:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.CustomerAccount;
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerAccount
(
  PlanID int PRIMARY KEY, 
  DateOpened datetime NOT NULL,
  PlanType AS 
    CASE -- NOTE: casting as varchar(12) will make the column a varchar(12) column:
      WHEN LEFT(PlanID,3) = 100 THEN CAST('Basic' AS varchar(12))
      ELSE 'Professional' 
    END 
  PERSISTED
);
INSERT dbo.CustomerAccount (PlanID, DateOpened)
VALUES (100123, '20160114'), (100999, '20151210'), (255657, '20150617');
```

Notice that I use CAST to assign the data type, the table will be created with this column as varchar(12).

Now the index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_CustomerAccount ON dbo.CustomerAccount(DateOpened) 
INCLUDE (PlanType);
```

Let's test again:

```
SELECT DateOpened, PlanType FROM dbo.CustomerAccount;
```

Execution plan:

[image]

... again, it used the nonclustered index

A third option, which I don't have time to go into, would be to create an indexed view. This would be a good option for you if you were unable to change your existing table structure.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 allows creating indexes on computed columns, but you're not doing that -- you're attempting to create the index directly on an *expression*. This is not allowed. You'll have to make `PlanType` a column first:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerAccount ADD PlanType AS LEFT(PlanID, 3);
```

And now creating the index will work just fine (if your `SET` options are all correct, as [outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189292)):

```
CREATE INDEX ixn_DateOpened_CustomerAccount ON CustomerAccount(DateOpened) INCLUDE (PlanType)
```

It is not required that you mark the column `PERSISTED`. This is required only if the column is not precise, which does not apply here (this is a concern only for floating-point data).

Incidentally, the real benefit of this index is not so much that `LEFT(PlanType, 3)` is precalculated (the calculation is inexpensive), but that no clustered index lookup is needed to get at `PlanID`. With an index only on `DateOpened`, a query like

```
SELECT PlanType FROM CustomerAccounts WHERE DateOpened >= '2012-01-01'
```

will result in an index seek on `CustomerAccounts`, followed by a clustered index lookup to get `PlanID` (so we can calculate `PlanType`). If the index *does* include `PlanType`, the index is covering and the extra lookup disappears.

This benefit is relevant only if the index is truly covering, however. If you select other columns from the table, an index lookup is still required and the included computed column is only taking up space for little gain. Likewise, suppose that you had multiple calculations on `PlanID` or you needed `PlanID` itself as well -- in this case it would make much more sense to include `PlanID` directly rather than `PlanType`.

Answer (score 0):

Computed columns are only allowed in indexes if they are `Persisted` - that is, if the data is written to the table. If the information is not persisted, then the information isn't even calculated / available until the field is queried.

Comment: This is, plain and simply, incorrect. Computed columns do not need to be persisted to be indexed. They are implicitly persisted as part of the index. The only time you do need to persist the column is if you're dealing with floating point, which is not considered precise.

Comment: You are right - I haven't had to do this since SQL 2008, where the persisted requirement was still true. Thanks for calling this out.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no SQL Server 2008 instances anymore where I can test this, but from 2008R2 onwards already, `PERSISTED` is not required while the engine does persist the value in the index.